# Изменить текст у тега text конкретного элемента (this) d3.js

Tags: svg, d3.js

Не могу присвоить конкретному элементу текст при 'drag'т.е. this не работает, меняется у всех элементов разом.

```js
const svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
  .attr('width', 800)
  .attr('height', 400);

const barHeight = 400,
  padding = 1,
  dataSet = [];


for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  dataSet.push(i)
}


let bars = svg.selectAll('g')
  .data(dataSet)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .append('rect')
  .classed('plot-bar', true)
  .attr('y', 0)
  .attr('x', (d, i) => i * 30)
  .attr('width', 30 - padding)
  .attr('height', barHeight);

let text = svg.selectAll("g")
  .append('text')
  .attr("x", (d, i) => i * 30)
  .attr("y", 15)
  .text(400);

let dragg = d3.drag()
  .on('drag', () => {
    let x = d3.event.sourceEvent.x;
    bars.each(function() {
      let r = this.getBoundingClientRect();
      r.x < x && r.width + r.x > x ? d3.select(this).attr('height', d3.event.sourceEvent.y) : false;
    })
    text.text(d3.event.sourceEvent.y);
  })

svg.call(dragg);
```

```css
.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.plot {
  border: 2px solid #789;
  background-color: burlywood;
}

.plot-bar {
  fill: teal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно присвоить текстовым тегам класс, и искать их по нему:

```js
const svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
  .attr('width', 600)
  .attr('height', 400);

const barHeight = 400,
  padding = 1,
  dataSet = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  dataSet.push(400)
}

let bars = svg.selectAll('g')
  .data(dataSet)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .append('rect')
  .classed('plot-bar', true)
  .attr('y', 0)
  .attr('x', (d, i) => i * 30)
  .attr('width', 30 - padding)
  .attr('height', barHeight);

let text = svg.selectAll("g")
  .append('text')
  .attr("x", (d, i) => i * 30)
  .attr("class", (d, i) => `text${i}`)
  .attr("y", 15)
  .text(2500);

let dragg = () => {
  let x = d3.event.sourceEvent.x;
  bars.each(function(d, i) {
    let r = this.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (r.x < x && r.width + r.x > x) {
      let y = Math.max(0, Math.min(d3.event.sourceEvent.y - r.y, 400));
      d3.select(this).datum(y);
      d3.select(this).attr('height', y);
    };
  })
  recalc(); 
};

svg.call(d3.drag().on('start', dragg).on('drag', dragg));
  
function recalc() {
  bars.each((d, i) => d3.select(`.text${i}`).text((d/400*(+height.value)).toFixed()));
}
```

```css
.plot-bar {
  fill: teal;
}

svg {
  background-color: burlywood;
}

text {
  font-size:14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<input value=2500 id=height onkeyup=recalc() /><hr>
```

Comment: Спасибо @Stranger in the Q. Странно, что метода нет, для this.

Comment: @spoon100500 он есть, но тогда нужно итерироваться по группам, а не по прямоугольникам, больше кода поменять придется

Comment: подскажите, если пиксели перевести в см, насколько реальные размеры будут отображаться? По ним можно сделать раскрой в реальности))

Comment: @spoon100500 боюсь это невозможно, я думаю надо считать в %

Comment: Мне нужна реальная высота в см т.к. в дальнейшем этот эскиз уйдет в производство для резки ламелей. Погрешность округляется в 0,5 еденицы т.е. 115,2=115; 115,7=115,5

Comment: @spoon100500 я к тому что если Вам известна полная высота, та что сейчас 400, то можно в % от нее посчитать

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99295/discussion-between-spoon-100500-and-stranger-in-the-q).

Comment: @StrangerintheQ http://learn.javascript.ru/ninja-code  к прочтению .Потому что ну проста очень трудно понять ваш код.

Comment: @Demon__ANT я это все читал, однако я не понял к чему это

Comment: У вас  `r,x,y` короткие имена переменных а там говорится что __Короткая переменная прячется в коде лучше, чем ниндзя в лесу__ Я к тому что понять очень сложно ваш код

Comment: @Demon__ANT но это же код из вопроса..

Comment: @StrangerintheQ =( упс прошу прощения не обратил внимание.

Comment: @Demon__ Но на самом деле я я не вижу ничего плохого в том, что локальная переменная внутри метода называется коротко, когда их мало и их объявления перед глазами - в них сложно запутаться. другое дело переменные классов или другие публичные вещи. Видели же шейдеры? вот если там в какой нибудь трассировке лучей изменить названия переменных с `ro` и `rd` на `rayOrigin` и `rayDirection` то убиться можно насколько длиннее листинг каждого, к ним очень много обращений. Лично я хуже понимаю код, который нужно постоянно скроллить вверх-вниз, отдаю предпочтение функциям которые влезают в экран.

Comment: Эта переменная лишняя let r = svg.node().getBoundingClientRect();?

Comment: @spoon100500 отчего же, там проверка с ней

Comment: @Stranger in the Qlet наверное с ней проверка r = this.getBoundingClientRect();?

Comment: @spoon100500 а ведь да, я ее добавлял для того чтобы учесть положение картинки при скролле страницы, однако видимо не дописал этот момент, отвлекся наверное =], буду у компа - гляну

Comment: Ещё такой вопрос, не понимаю зачем добавлять класс .text и искать его в цикле, разве нельзя найти тег <text> для изменения текста?

Comment: @spoon100500 да можно, как достучитесь так и можно =)

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Отличный ответ. Но почему такая краткость? На мой взгляд, необходимо давать хоть краткое описание.  Что делает программа, как пользоваться. Я например не сразу увидел, что программа имеет практическое применение - типа расчета какие  доски, сколько и размер каждой доски будет при нанесении определенных контуров, типа вырезанного окна..

Comment: @Alexandr_TT возможно, это были дополнительные пожелания из чата - это расчет высоты штор

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
  const svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('width', 800)
    .attr('height', 400);

  const barHeight = 800,
    padding = 1,
    dataSet = [];


  for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    dataSet.push(i)
  }

  let bars = svg.selectAll('g')
    .data(dataSet)
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .append('rect')
    .classed('plot-bar', true)
    .attr('y', 0)
    .attr('x', (d, i) => i * 30)
    .attr('width', 30 - padding)
    .attr('height', barHeight);

  let text = svg.selectAll("g")
    .append('text')
    .attr("x", (d, i) => i * 30)
    .attr("y", 15)
    .text(400);

  let dragg = d3.drag()
    .on('drag', () => {
      let x = d3.event.sourceEvent.x;
      let y = d3.event.sourceEvent.y;
      bars.each(function(i) {
        let r = this.getBoundingClientRect();
        if (r.x < x && r.width + r.x > x) {
          d3.select(this).attr('height', y);
          this.nextSibling.innerHTML = y;
        }
      })
    });

  svg.call(dragg);

</script>
```

Comment: ну да, они же уже в группах :)